# How to pipe sort to gawk?

Tags: awk, pipe, sort, gawk

I'm having trouble trying to pipe a sort with a gawk. I currently have:

```
gawk -f p3a01.awk unsortedNames.txt | sort | gawk -f p3a01.awk
```

this is however giving me the wrong results. The gawk seems to work fine if I do something like:

```
gawk -f p3a01.awk unsortedNames.txt | sort > test1.out
gawk -f p3a01.awk test1.out
```

I'm not sure if there is a proper way to directly pipe sort to gawk. I would ideally like to do this all on one line

Snip of `unsortedNames.txt`:

```
Faye King
Lenny R Graph
I M Board
Grey White
```

`p3a01.awk`   (prints last name first then rest of the name):

```
BEGIN{}
{
      printf $NF " ";
      $NF="";
      print $0;
}
END{}
```

`p3a02.awk` (prints the file in the original order after it has been ordered by last name):

```
BEGIN{}
{
     for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
         printf $i " ";
     }
     print $1;
}
END{}
```

Final result (sorted by last name):

```
I M Board
Lenny R Graph
Faye King
Grey White
```

Comment: @SatōKatsura fixed. I've added my scripts.

Comment: post how should look the expected result

Comment: What does not work? It works for me given the data that you present.  Did you create these files on a Windows machine (this may create problems with carriage returns (DOS newlines)). Run the files through `dos2unix`.  If that does not help, describe or show the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized *single-processed* GNU **Awk** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" }
     { a[$NF]=$0 }END{ for(i in a) print a[i] }' unsortedNames.txt
```

---

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` - comparison/sorting by array keys/indices. We are able to set predefined array `PROCINFO` to one of a set of predefined values. Those special values described here(documentation): https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning

---

The output:

```
I M Board
Lenny R Graph
Faye King
Grey White
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working as advertised, so whatever errors you're experiencing may be related to invisible characters in the input data (`\r` at the end of lines?).

I noticed that you are *removing* the last field when you are transforming the data for `sort`.  This is not necessary.  You just need to prepend each line with the last field, and then remove it again after the `sort`:

```
$ awk '{ print $NF, $0 }' file | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
I M Board
Lenny R Graph
Faye King
Grey White
```

The `cut` command will output all space-delimited fields from the second onwards.